# How to close one single tab in android tablayout without clearing all the tabs and adding again

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

There is a method to add a tab in `TabHost` as well as clear all tabs, but there are no APIs to remove one single tab.

Following the logic in `clearAllTabs` tried to

```
tabwidget.removeViewAt(index);
tabHost.getTabContentView().removeViewAt(index)
```

After this the behaviour is strange. I assume that is because the `mTabSpecs` still contain the tabspec reference. `mTabSpecs` is a private variable in `TabHost` and there are not get methods to get a handle to this.

How to resolve the issue if one wants to close a single tab, and yes I have tried to clear all the tabs and add back all the tabspecs. It does not work for my usecase where some views contains some information regarding a session. If I recreate those tabspecs, I will go back to the starting point in those views.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `Visibility` of the `Tab` that you want to `close` to `View.GONE`.

Comment: yes i tried that, but when i set it, the tabcount still returns the tab whose visibility is set to View.GONE. Also when i want the tab to reappear, it will only appear at the place where it existed at the first time. For example if the tab index was 1 and i set the visibility to GONE, then i open another tab and if i want to show my previously closed tab, it will open at the same index, which will not be an ideal UI experience.

Answer (score 0):

resolved with the View.GONE but with method which specifically checks for the visibility before counting the tabs. drawback is the index of the view cannot be changed.